# Italics in the enumerate environment

Tags: formatting, lists, enumerate

I want to use italics in the enumerate environment. I want to have the following output:

> *(a)*  Text1
>     *(b)*  Text2
>     *(c)*  Text3

I am using:

```
\begin{enumerate}[(a)] \end{enumerate}
```

How do I change this to get the desired results?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you seem to be using the `enumerate` package, you can just add `\itshape` to your enumeration:

```
\begin{enumerate}[\itshape(a)]
```

Answer (score 15):

Based on your code fragment, I guess you are using the package `enumerate` or `paralist`. However, I recommend the package [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

By using the package [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) you can use:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),font=\itshape]
```

If you want to set it as default you can use:

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\alph*),font=\itshape}
```

and then you can type:

```
\begin{enumerate}
```

without any specification.